# Site didn't send any data and won't load fast and whole content after some interval

Tags: wordpress, caching, web, hosting, server-side

I have a wordpress website. When I try to open my website it takes more time to load. Also when I try to open Admin panel the same problem is arrived and browser shows like "Your site didn't send any data" error with err_empty_response code. Website and admin panel works normally sometime and suddenly the error starts. Is that hosting problem ? Also the whole content of website is not loading.

error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link for the same?

Comment: @MukeshRam yes sure. it is http://competitionmantra.com

Comment: It seems your server is having connectivity issue. You need to contact your hosting for this issue.

Comment: I contacted the person from where i purchased hosting. He said that it is a timeout problem.

Comment: @MukeshRam want to look inside admin panel ?

Comment: Yes if you can provide.

Comment: should i need to provide here ?

Comment: Please join here in the chat room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134143/wordpress-discussion

Comment: I doesn't have a required reputation. any other way ?

Comment: I have an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565845/wp-admin-err-empty-response/47627931#47627931 It may help.