# wp-admin - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

When I try to access my `wp-admin` I'm getting on some specific sites `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

This includes - plugins, themes, general settings and more. Some areas are still accessible, like Pages or Posts.

I tried basically everything. I renamed the plugins folder and themes folder, it didn't work. Then I removed the whole WP install (I kept `wp-content`, it contains a lot of stuff), and reinstalled everything (`wp-admin`, `wp-includes` etc). And it still didn't work. I changed all permissions to `755` with `chmod -R 755` ... and still no effect.

The thing is - it was totally random. I actually didn't install anything or change anything in the last week. I suspect that it is a problem with my host, AWS. It might be firewall settings or something like that?

I'm completely lost and a hint or some kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

"ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE: The website didn't send any data, and might be down." - thats Chromes article (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?vid=0-175552448314-1493325043142&visit_id=1-636289218508828898-695176163&rd=1)
This link might work:
(https://www.wiknix.com/solved-err_empty_response-no-data-received/)

Comment: The thing is that its happening on multiple computers that are not on the same network

Answer (score 0):

The error message **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** can happen with some servers. In my case happened with GoDaddy server.

To fix this, switch the Editor Loader Method as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and [this](https://www.easytechguides.com/google-chrome-connection-errors.html) link helped me a lot,Method 10 worked for me.

1. right-click on the network icon located in the notification area of the taskbar and then click on "Open Network and Sharing Center".
2. Click on "Change adapter settings" (top left).
3. Right click on your network and choose "Properties".
4. Select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click on "Properties".
5. Select "Use the following DNS server addresses".
6. Type the DNS server numbers.
   208.67.222.222 
   208.67.220.220

Change DNS Server Addresses to OpenDNS
7. Check "Validate settings upon exit".

8. Click on "OK".
9. Click on "Close".

Windows will now check for problems and if there are problems try to resolve it.

10. Now it's time to clear (flush) Google Chrome's DNS cache. To do this, open Google Chrome.
11. Type chrome://net-internals/#dns in the address bar and press Enter.
12. Click on the ▼ icon located at the top right.
13. Click on "Clear cache".
14. Click on "Flush sockets".

Clear Cache & Flush Sockets in Google Chrome
15. Restart Google Chrome.

Comment: This is a server issue that the server didn't send any data, why would it be a problem with the client?